# App ID for XCode iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-id

So for my App ID, I'm registering it, I realize the format is com.companyname.appname so two questions

1. My app has a space in it, so while registering the app name how should I identify the space? Would it be .app-name? (If the app was called App Name)
2. I'm registered as an Apple developer through a personal account so it's my name rather than a company name, although there is a name I do want to use as a company name for the App ID, that eventually I do want to form into an actual company and eventually transfer the account under an account name. So my question is, in the App ID, should I or should I not use that hypothetical Company name although the company doesn't legally exist yet? I do own the domain so company-name.com (com.company-name, in the App ID) would be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) ".app-name" should be fine for "App Name". Even ".whateverIWant" would be fine for "App Name".

2) I have published an app where I used my name as the company name in com.companyname.appname is my name but the app was published under someone else's name. I don't think that would affect your app much.

The only major thing that is important about the app id is that it matches in all places, in the app, the certificate, and iTunes connect.